# Convert List of Lists to Dictionary with unique keys and all related values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm python newbie and I'am currently struggling with one problem. I have a list of lists:

`[[0,1], [1,2,8], [3,4], [4,2], [2,5], [5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12]]`

My aim is to make a dictionary from it with the following format:

`{0:[1],1:[2,8],2:[8,1,4,5],3:[4],5:[6,7,2],6:[5,7],7:[5,6],8:[1,2,10,9,11,12],9:[8,10,11,12],10:[8,9,11,12],11:[12,10,9,8],12:[11,9,10,8]}`.

In short:

> It has to make a dictionary with unique keys from 1 to 12 in this case (all unique numbers in a list), and to each key it assigns a list of values, which is a common subset for this key i.e for key `2` it appears in lists `[4,2], [2,5], [1,2,8]` so it has to assign to a key `2` a value which is a list of numbers in those 3 lists except 2.

Thus the output for key `2` should be: `2:[8,1,4,5]` etc.

I've made some code:

```
data = [[0,1], [1,2,8], [3,4], [4,2], [2,5], [5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12]]

graph = {}
for i in range(13):
    graph[i] = 3

numbers = list(range(0,13))
for row in data:
    for i in graph.keys():
        if i in row:
            graph[i] = row

for key,value in graph.items():
    graph[key] = graph[key][1:]

print(graph)
```

Yet, it gives me output:

`{0: [1], 1: [2, 8], 2: [5], 3: [4], 4: [2], 5: [6, 7], 6: [6, 7], 7: [6, 7], 8: [9, 10, 11, 12], 9: [9, 10, 11, 12], 10: [9, 10, 11, 12], 11: [9, 10, 11, 12], 12: [9, 10, 11, 12]}`

I really don't know how to combine those lists from this in such a way that I will get desired output.

Comment: Why `2: [8,1,4,5]`? sublists appear `[1,2,8], [3,4], [4,2], [2,5]`, so it should be `2: [1, 8, 4, 5]`. Also why `1: [2, 8]` and not `1: [0, 2, 8]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to fix your code specifically or are you just looking for a solution?

```
data = [[0,1], [1,2,8], [3,4], [4,2], [2,5], [5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12]]
n = 12

# Create dict with empty list for each key
result = {key: [] for key in range(n + 1)}

for key in result:
    for x in data:
        if key in x:
            # We need to make a copy of `x` because otherwise we'd modify `data`
            x = x.copy()
            x.remove(key)
            result[key].extend(x)

print(result)
```

It's an approach with emphasis on clarity so I'm sure [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time_(program_lifecycle_phase)) could still be improved. It prints:

```
{0: [1], 1: [0, 2, 8], 2: [1, 8, 4, 5], 3: [4], 4: [3, 2], 5: [2, 6, 7], 6: [5, 7], 7: [5, 6], 8: [1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 12], 9: [8, 10, 11, 12], 10: [8, 9, 11, 12], 11: [8, 9, 10, 12], 12: [8, 9, 10, 11]}
```

Also, does the order matter?

Answer (score 2):

```
d=dict()
entries=[]
for i in range(0,13):
    entries=[]
    for j in data:
        if i in j:
            entries+=[num for num in j if num!=i]
    d[i]=entries
```

Output

```
{0: [1],
 1: [0, 2, 8],
 2: [1, 8, 4, 5],
 3: [4],
 4: [3, 2],
 5: [2, 6, 7],
 6: [5, 7],
 7: [5, 6],
 8: [1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 9: [8, 10, 11, 12],
 10: [8, 9, 11, 12],
 11: [8, 9, 10, 12],
 12: [8, 9, 10, 11]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = [[0,1], [1,2,8], [3,4], [4,2], [2,5], [5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12]]

d = defaultdict(list) # a dictionary with all values defaulting to lists

for lst in mylist:
    for val in lst:
        # extend each list with new values provided they aren't
        # equal to the key in question
        d[val].extend([x for x in lst if x!=val])

d
# {0: [1], 1: [0, 2, 8], 2: [1, 8, 4, 5], 8: [1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 12], 3: [4], 4: [3, 2], 5: [2, 6, 7], 6: [5, 7], 7: [5, 6], 9: [8, 10, 11, 12], 10: [8, 9, 11, 12], 11: [8, 9, 10, 12], 12: [8, 9, 10, 11]}
```

By using a defaultdict, you don't have to worry about assigning a list to the value by default, so you can just use the standard `list` attributes like `append` and `extend`.

There is a performance consideration, as you iterate over `lst` N+1 times, where N is the length of `lst`. `extend` is an O(N) operation, so building the list *and* extending the existing one isn't exactly performant. It also won't account for duplicate values (if that matters to you). However, it's a bit cleaner than trying to use a standard `dict`, which you could do:

```py
d = {}
for lst in mylist:
    for val in lst:
        if val not in d:
            d[val] = [x for x in lst if x!=val]
        else:
            d[val].extend([x for x in lst if x!=val])

d
# {0: [1], 1: [0, 2, 8], 2: [1, 8, 4, 5], 8: [1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 12], 3: [4], 4: [3, 2], 5: [2, 6, 7], 6: [5, 7], 7: [5, 6], 9: [8, 10, 11, 12], 10: [8, 9, 11, 12], 11: [8, 9, 10, 12], 12: [8, 9, 10, 11]}
```

Where you have to check if `val` is in the dictionary to build the `list`, otherwise, you can modify the value in-place with `extend`

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning `graph[i]` to only one row, so if you come across another row containing i, the answers from your initial row will get reassigned. Instead you might want to assign an empty list to `graph[i]` instead of 3 append to `graph[i]` instead.

```
graph = {}
for i in range(13):
  graph[i] = []

for row in data:
  for i in graph.keys():
    if i in row:
      for val in row:
        if val != i:
          graph[i].append(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[[0,1], [1,2,8], [3,4], [4,2], [2,5], [5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12]]
from collections import defaultdict


dic=defaultdict(list)
for i,v in enumerate(a):
    for j, v2 in enumerate(v):        
        new_s=a[i][:j]+a[i][j+1:]
        dic[v2].extend(new_s)

for i in dic:
    dic[i]=list(set(dic[i]))

print(dict(dic))
```

output

```
{0: [1],
 1: [0, 8, 2],
 2: [8, 1, 4, 5],
 8: [1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 3: [4],
 4: [2, 3],
 5: [2, 6, 7],
 6: [5, 7],
 7: [5, 6], 
 9: [8, 10, 11, 12],
 10: [8, 9, 11, 12], 
 11: [8, 9, 10, 12],
 12: [8, 9, 10, 11]
 }
```